# MockMvc gets Ambiguous handler methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I have these controllers:

```
@PostMapping(
  value = Endpoints.GET_PRICE,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    headers = {"Accept=*/*"})
public ResponseEntity<PricesResponse> getPrice(
  @RequestBody @Validated({PriceRequestValidationCheck.class}) PriceRequest priceRequest) {
  PricesResponse defaultPriceResponse =
    priceService.generateAllPricesForWeb(priceRequest, Optional.empty());
  return ResponseEntity.ok(defaultPriceResponse);
}

@PostMapping(
  value = Endpoints.GET_PRICE,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    headers = {"Accept=application/vnd.price.v2+json"})
public ResponseEntity<PricesResponse> getPriceV2(
  @RequestBody @Validated({PriceRequestValidationCheckV2.class}) PriceRequest priceRequest, HttpServletRequest request) {
  PricesResponse defaultPriceResponse =
    priceService.generateAllPricesForWeb(
      priceRequest,
        Optional.of(
          request
            .getHeader("Accept")
            .replace("application/vnd.price.v", "")
            .replace("+json", "")));
return ResponseEntity.ok(defaultPriceResponse);
}
```

When I execute a test which runs:

```
private MvcResult callPriceEndPoint(MediaType acceptHeader) throws Exception {
  return mockMvc
    .perform(
      MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(GET_PRICE_PATH)
        .content(getJsonString(getPriceRequest()))
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(acceptHeader))
          .andExpect(status().is5xxServerError())
          .andReturn();
}
```

It gices this error:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/api/price': {public...

`Endpoints.GET_PRICE` is `/api/price`.

I understand that `callPriceEndPoint` doesn't know which controller to use but how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

using different url only it is possible. means the @postmapping, value should be unique for each method.

@postmapping(value="/api/price")  cannot be used with another post mapping. In your case, you mapped both post methods with same url.  change one value to differnt url apart from "url/price", it will work

Comment: That makes sense. I only ask as I thought the specification of the Accept header on getPriceV2 and the wildcard header on getPrice would allow for the correct routing. It works as I wish when I submit a request through Postman. Just not in my test using MockMvc.